# How to refresh foreign key drop downs on admin forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I've got an app running on Django that allows configuration through the admin interface. One of the models has four different fields that point to a model that details a variety of metadata about dates. *Most* of the time, each field will refer to different details, but, sometimes, a user needs to have two of them pointing at one instance and the other two pointing at another instance.

The default django admin form for the model has a handy-dandy drop down and add button for each of the four fields. If you add one of these date metadata objects, the other drop downs aren't updated. If you go to add that same constraint, you rightfully encounter a foreign key constraint error. In order to reuse these instances, you have to save the form and reload it.

Is there a way to either have the form refresh the drop downs when a new instance is added and assigned or have a new creation perform a get-or-create rather than just a create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the solution and it required two major steps:

1. Adding a custom javascript file
2. Attaching an onchange handler for each tied drop down

The first was easy. Under the admin class, all you have to do is declare the js file to include:

```
class ExampleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ("app/js/ExampleAdmin.js",)
```

Make sure that that following `,` is present so that python recognizes that as a tuple.

The `onchange` handler was difficult at first. There are several ways to add an `onchange` handler, but *only one* works here. Say I've got the functions:

```
function earliest_changed() {...}
function latest_changed() {...}
function earliest_issued_changed() {...}
function latest_issued_changed() {...}
```

Personally, I'd immediately attach via:

```
$(function() {
    $("select#id_earliest_date").change(earliest_changed);
    $("select#id_latest_date").change(latest_changed);
    $("select#id_earliest_issued_date").change(earliest_issued_changed);
    $("select#id_latest_issued_date").change(latest_issued_changed);
});
```

That did not work. I got the same result when using `...on("change", functionName)` and `...addEventListener("change", functionName)`. Instead, what ultimately worked was:

```
$(function() {
    $("select#id_earliest_date")[0].onchange = earliest_changed;
    $("select#id_latest_date")[0].onchange = latest_changed;
    $("select#id_earliest_issued_date").onchange = earliest_issued_changed;
    $("select#id_latest_issued_date")[0].onchange = latest_issued_changed;
});
```

There was custom functionality for handling the return value for the foreign key popup editor. As a result, it *had* to use the `onchange` member of the element. Anything else would be ignored.

**TL;DR:**

1. Create a new js file
2. Create `onchange` event handlers for each tied foreign key field
3. Create an 'on page load' function
4. Assign the `onchange` event handlers using `$("select#id_member_name")[0].onchange = handler;` within the page load function
5. Create a nested class within your admin class named `Media`
6. Add a tuple member to `Media` named `js`
7. Add the proper path to your new script in `js`

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to solve this issue is to make the ForeignKey field an autocomplete input rather than the default `<select>` dropdown. In your case, it could look like this (I only show one ForeignKey field):

**models.py**

```py
class DateMetadata(models.Model):
    data = models.CharField()

class Example(models.Model):
    date_metadata = models.ForeignKey('DateMetadata')
```

**admin.py**

```py
from .models import DateMetadata, Example

class DateMetadataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = DateMetadata
    search_fields = ['data']

class ExampleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Example
    autocomplete_fields = ['date_metadata']
```

See the [`autocomplete_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) doc for more details.